# Paypal checkout in web view

Tags: mobile, paypal, webview

I have a web site that I'm working on which has a fully implemented paypal checkout flow.  We're working on a mobile client which re-uses this flow to accomplish checkouts.

Unfortunately, when we redirect to the paypal site, we get the full desktop style, rather than  layout and styles tailored to mobile.

Is there any URL parameter I can supply or different approach I have to take so that the checkout is usable on a mobile device?

The URL we're redirecting to looks like this:

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-LOTSOFNUMBERS`

Answer (score 0):

That's odd.  I never realized Adaptive Payments didn't automatically kick in to the mobile.  I know Express Checkout does, so you could switch to that unless you had some specific need for the Adaptive platform..??

If you do stick with adaptive check out the [options for the checkout flow](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). You can do an iframe and other things that might work better for mobile.  There's a lot of info at that link about it.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between adaptive and mobile?  I feel like I'd have to author a whole new flow if I was to switch?

Comment: The Adaptive Payments platform is just what they called that new set of API's when they launched it.  You'll notice on their developer site it says "The MPL uses the Adaptive Payments API (a PayPal Classic API)."  So the Mobile Payments Library is built on top of the Adaptive Payments API.

Comment: Yeah, if you switch to Express Checkout you'd have to re-integrate using the different API's.  If you're working with PHP, though, my [class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) would make that pretty quick and easy.